# SAP creating TDC in ECATT with Variant parameter = sy-datum

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I just started with ECATT and I need some help here.

I am trying to create a Test Data Container for my ABAP-UNIT-Tests and I would like to give a parameter type 'D' (date) the default value the current date (sy-datum).

Until now I have set up the parameters with static values, is it posible to set parameters or variants with dynamic values?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jagger, but my question is also how do you do it.